# C linked list and pointers

Tags: c, pointers

Can somebody please explain what this code with pointers does:

```
    while(terminate== 0)
    {
        s->value=s->next->value; 
        if ((s->next->next)==NULL)
        {
            free(s->next); 
            s->next=NULL;
            terminate= 1;
        }
        s=s->next;
    }
```

where s is passed as a parameter as : set_el* s and having this structure below:

```
 typedef struct set_el
 {
   int value;
    struct set_el* next;
 } set_el;
```

Comment: seems like poor code -- dereferencing before checking for NULL `s->next->value` -- but generally speaking it looks like it is shortening a list with one

Comment: This code is a glittering jewel of negative reenforcement. It is a testimonial of how *not* to remove a node from a linked list. The only thing it is missing to officially trump all other comers is a recursive element, and even with that missing it is still a strong contender .

Comment: This looks like a whats wrong with this code homework assignment.. not actual code

Answer (score 6):

In case of NULL input it will cause a segmentation fault since `s->value` is illegal.

On a list of size 1 it will similarly fail because s->next->value is illegal.

On a list with a loop (for instance a>b>a...) it will loop endlessly because s->next->next will never be NULL

Finally on a linked list of size 2 or above it will traverse the list coping the value of the next node to the current node and delete the last node.

Effectively it will 'remove' the first node in the list in a very roundabout way. (We free up the last node memory but we copy the values up the list. The new list is 1 node shorter and without the value in the first node).